# How to know if an element, created dynamically, exist?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textnode

I have this simple function:

```
var x = document.createTextNode("ERROR");
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

So then I need to create an **IF** to verify if this message exist [If this message has been created]. This is the problem, I don't know how to do that.

**GetElementByID** seems to don't work with element created by dynamically.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: `getElementById()` works for all elements, as long as they are in the DOM.  You're making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: It's the same with jQuery's .length, works on dynamic elements too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a text node, not an element. You need to create an element and give it an id to be able to use `getElementById`.

I don't know of any reasonable way to search for a text node, although you could always check the text nodes of the element you attached it to and see if it's there.

```
var message = "ERROR";
var t = document.createTextNode(message);
var node = document.getElementById('content').appendChild(t);
if (document.getElementById('content').innerHTML !== message) {

  console.log('element not added');
} else {
  console.log('element added');
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/btipling/rBg4w/

Comment: In-case you want to know, you can check a `textNode` via `Node.contains`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.contains` to check if a element is in the DOM

Just a quick example of how it works

```
document.contains($('<div>')[0]); // FALSE
```

And

```
document.contains($('<div>').appendTo('body')[0]); // TRUE
```

jQuery only used for a shorthand to element creation

This also works for **text nodes** and you can use contains on any node.

```
document.body.contains(Node); // Example
```

The browser support is somewhat very **good**

**Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains**

---

Question specifics:

```
var x = document.createTextNode("ERROR");
document.body.appendChild(x);
document.contains(x); // Should be TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work:

```
var x = document.createTextNode("ERROR");
var element = document.body.appendChild(x); //returns text node
if(!element){
    //element was not added
}
```

although if I were you I might create a span element with an id or a class called error. This way you can apply any css styles to it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var x = document.createTextNode("ERROR");
document.body.appendChild(x);

if (document.body.innerText.indexOf('ERROR')>=0){
    alert('"ERROR" found');
}
```

indexOf doesn't work in all browsers.

As @slowpython said I'd rather create a DOM element with ID or NAME.

Comment: `indexOf` does work in all browsers, `innerText` however does not, plus this doesn't actually confirm that the node is in the DOM **-1**